# Core dump while implementing binary tree travers

Tags: c++, error-handling, tree

I trying to implement binary tree with persons.
Any person got father and mother.
In my main() function it works good until I add person to my first "X"s father.
My main gets Aborted (core dumped) error on the 4th addFather("Y","F") call, and I cant realize what is my fault.

```
Person& findPerson(Person* root, string child_name){
    if(root == nullptr) throw exception();
    else if(root->name.compare(child_name) == 0) return *root;
    else{
        if(root->father == nullptr)return findPerson(root->mother, child_name);
        else if(root->mother == nullptr)return findPerson(root->father, child_name);
        else {
            return findPerson(root->mother, child_name);
            return findPerson(root->father, child_name);
        }

    }
}

family::Person::Person(string person_name){
    name = person_name;
    father = nullptr;
    mother = nullptr;

};

family::Person::Person(string person_name, bool is_male){
    name = person_name;
    father = nullptr;
    mother = nullptr;
    isMale = is_male;

};



// TREE
family::Tree::Tree(string name){
    root = new Person(name);
};

family::Tree& Tree::addFather(string child, string father){
    Person& child_found = findPerson(root, child);
    Person* f = new Person(father, true);
    child_found.father = f;

    return *this;
    };


family::Tree& family::Tree::addMother(string child, string mother){
    Person& child_found = findPerson(root, child);
    Person* f = new Person(mother, false);
    child_found.mother = f;
    return *this;
    };
int main(){
    Tree t("X");

    t.addFather("X","Y");
    t.addMother("X", "Z");
    t.addFather("Z", "W");
    t.addFather("Y","F");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that once a function hits a return it exits.  You have `return findPerson(root->mother, child_name);` then `return findPerson(root->father, child_name);` on consecutive lines. The second return will never execute.

Comment: Yes, that is in findPerson()

Comment: So how can I make  two of them execute ? I probably making some recursive fail.

Comment: I think you should change the signature to return a pointer instead of a reference. Then you could compare the pointer returned to nullptr. In this case you probably want to get rid of the `if(root == nullptr) throw exception();` and instead return nullptr if root == nullptr

Comment: Actually your solution works! what is the explanation for my error was?

Comment: Strange issue if I remove the returns it stops working.

Comment: It should not work without the returns. That will be Undefined Behavior. A function that is non void must return a value.

Comment: I could fix this however it would take me 10 minutes or so to rewrite your entire code (and test) and the problem is I have to leave now for work.

Comment: For my suggested edit instead of the first return you set a pointer variable to `findPerson(root->mother, child_name);` then check if that is a nullptr. If it is not null return it. If it is null `return findPerson(root->father, child_name);` then in your `addFather()` and `addMother()` check for nullptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs work, but one hint is that if you throw an exception you must [catch it](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/144-uncaught-exceptions-catch-all-handlers-and-exception-specifiers/). It is not well defined in C++ what happens when an exception is not caught, and so this may well be your problem.

So, for example the,

```
if(root->father == nullptr)return findPerson(root->mother, child_name);
```

does not check if BOTH mother & father are null. If they are, it will call findPerson with nullptr. This will then make the function throw.

As a hint, on a linux system, the best way to find these issues is to use gdb. The command "catch throw" followed by "start" and the "continue", will catch any exceptions thrown. "bt" will then show you how you got there. GDB is (lets face it) an awful throw-back, which is impenetrable to most beginners, however, just like vi, it is a good skill to know at least the basics.

Quick start guide.
https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/